# AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute '_Item__name'

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an item object in a function, but when I try to print out the item's attributes I get errors.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\AddSales.py", line 184, in <module>
    if (collectSerials(salesOrderInfo[0], salesOrderInfo[1], salesOrderInfo[2], itemInfo[0], itemInfo[1] ,itemList) == 1):
  File ".\AddSales.py", line 62, in collectSerials
    print(item.getName())
  File ".\AddSales.py", line 109, in getName
    return self.__name
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute '_Item__name'
```

Object:
class Item:

```
def __init__(self, name, serialNumber, salesOrderNumber, shippingDate, salesInfo, warrantyExpiration):
    self.name = name
    self.serialNumber = serialNumber
    self.salesOrderNumber = salesOrderNumber
    self.shippingDate = shippingDate
    self.salesInfo = salesInfo
    self.warrantyExpiration = warrantyExpiration
```

function:

```
def collectSerials(salesOrderNum, shipDate, info, name, warranty, workingList=None):
    while 1:
    sn = input("Scan in the item's serial number, or enter \"done\" if finished scanning: \n")
    if (sn == "done"):
        break
    item = Item(name, sn, salesOrderNum, shipDate, info, warranty)
    print(item.getName())
    if (workingList is None):
        workingList = []
    workingList.append(item)


answer = input("Choose between the following options (Enter the corresponding number): \n1) Enter a different product \n2)Exit and finish sales order\n")

return answer
```

function call:

```
collectSerials(salesOrderInfo[0], salesOrderInfo[1], salesOrderInfo[2], itemInfo[0], itemInfo[1] ,itemList)
```

Comment: Can you show whole Item class? It seems that you are indeed using attribute that is not defined, i.e. `.__item` instead of `.item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepending a attribute name with two underscores (only) in Python triggers a special feature called name mangling. Python doesn't have truly private attributes. Instead, Python achieves "private" attributes by trying to hide them. This is achieved by mangling the attribute name with the class name. This error indicates you are trying to access `__item` outside of the class it was defined in. Given the following class:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private = object()

   def get_private(self):
       return self.__private
```

`__private` is actually stored as `_MyObject__private`.

```
obj = MyObject()
assert obj._MyObject__private is obj.get_private()
```

As you can see above, the attribute can still be accessed when outside the scope of a function that was defined on the class. You just need to know what to call it.

What this means is that if you try to access such an attribute from another class (such as a child subclass), then things can go wrong. Python doesn't know you mean to access the "private" attribute of another class and so the name gets mangled with the current class. eg.

```
class MyChild(MyObject):
    def swap_private(self, replacement):
        old = self.get_private() 
        # works! get_private is defined on MyObject and so fetches _MyObject__private
        self.__private = replacement 
        # silent error! Would actually store replacement in _MyChild__private
        return old


def set_private(obj, replacement):
    obj.__private = replacement
    # silent error! This function is not defined on a class and so just tries to directly
    # access `__private`
```

The simple solution is to not use double underscore names unless absolutely necessary. If you want to mark an attribute as private then just use a single underscore.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement an object as you would in Java using getters and setters which was the root of the problem.